# How to set up equations in python

Tags: python, math, numpy

I have a list with coefficients which define a system of equations I would like to solve. The first term in my list of coefficients is always 1 and the first variable in the solution is also assumed to be 1.

If

```
coeffs = [1,2,3,4]
```

then system of equations I would like to solve are the circular convolution of `coeffs` with the variables `[1, x[3], x[2], x[1]]`. In this way we get

```
1*1 + 2*x[3] + 3*x[2] + 4*x[1] = 0

1*x[3] + 2*x[2] + 3*x[1] + 4*1  = 0

1*x[2] + 2*x[1] + 3*1 + 4*x[3] = 0

1*x[1] + 2*1 + 3*x[3] + 4*x[2] = 0
```

Given `coeffs`, how can I set up this system of equations in numpy so I can solve for `x`? In practical cases `coeffs` will have length in the hundreds.

Comment: You have three unknowns (x[1], x[2], x[3]) and four equations, so in general (including the case `coeffs = [1, 2, 3, 4]`), there is no solution.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes thank you. In fact I really mostly want to test if a solution exists.

Comment: Might [Sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) help?

Comment: @atomh33ls An interesting question. I would be happy to use it if it did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> coeffs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> N = len(coeffs)
>>> a = np.tile(coeffs, (N, 1))
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> for i in xrange(1, N):
...     a[i] = np.roll(a[i], i)
... 
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 1]])
>>>
```

Comment: Or use http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.circulant.html or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html to create that Toeplitz matrix ... but how does this answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of simleo, you can generate it using numpy's speed (for larger data) instead of using a python loop:

```
>>> coeffs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> N = len(coeffs)
# Create coeffs matrix
>>> coeffs = np.tile(coeffs, (N, 1))

# Create grid of indexes
>>> rows, column_indices = np.ogrid[:N, :N]
# Create shift vector (shift each row by its index)
>>> shift = np.arange(N)
# Create shifted column indexes for each row
>>> column_indices = column_indices - shift[:, np.newaxis]

# Reorder
>>> coeffs = coeffs[rows, column_indices]
>>> coeffs
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 1]])
```

Given `coeffs = [1 2 3 4] = [a b c d]` and considering your variables `x = [1 x3 x2 x1]` you can transform the problem in a form `x3 * b + x2 * c + x1 *d = -a` (for your first case):

```
>>> a = coeffs[:, 1:]
>>> b = -coeffs[:, 0]
>>> np.linalg.lstsq(a,b)[0]
array([-0.47058824,  0.01960784, -0.47058824])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [1,20,300,4000]
>>> b = np.arr[a[n:]+a[:n] for n in range(4)]
>>> sol = np.linalg.solve(b[1:,1:],-b[1:,0])
>>> print "Using last N equations the solution is:", [1.0]+list(sol)
Using last N equations the solution is: [1.0, -0.11111111111111105, -0.11111111111111113, -1.2222222222222223]
>>> print "Substituting in first equation gives:", a[0]+sol.dot(a[1:]), "= 0"
Substituting in first equation gives: -4.44444444444 = 0
>>>
```

at this point your program can decide if the residual is too much or the solution is good enough.

If the solution is good enough, maybe you want to minimize the error using

```
>>> sol = numpy.linalg.lstsq(b[:,1:],-b[:,0])
```

note that the other element of the solution tuple give important insight into the nature of the least squares solution,

```
>>> print np.linspace.lstsq.__doc__
```

to know the whole story.

About efficiency, when you're going to solve a large system (NxN, almost...) of equations, you don't mind the 0.2s that you can shave with a pure numpy solution for building the coefficients matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) matrix of A denoted as A<sup>+</sup>. A solution exist if and only if AA<sup>+</sup>b = b and all solutions are given by
x = A<sup>+</sup>b + (I - A<sup>+</sup>A)*u

```
import numpy as np

def solvep(coeffs, tol=1e-10):
    a = np.array([np.roll(coeffs, i) for i, _ in enumerate(coeffs)])
    A, b = a[:, 1:], -a[:, 0]
    x = np.linalg.pinv(A).dot(b)
    z = np.abs(A.dot(x) - b)
    if np.all(z < tol):
        return x
    else:
        print "There is no solution, max error = {}".format(z.max())
    return None
```

Example:

```
>>> solvep([1,2,3,4])
There is no solution, max error = 2.1568627451
>>> solvep([1,1,1])
array([-0.33333333, -0.33333333, -0.33333333])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy linalg.solve

example from http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html

```
Solve the system of equations 3 * x0 + x1 = 9 and x0 + 2 * x1 = 8:

>>>
>>> a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
>>> b = np.array([9,8])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
>>> x
array([ 2.,  3.])
```

Comment: Thank you however this wasn't what I meant. I know how to solve the system of equations using numpy.linalg once they are set up. What I don't know how to do is to set them up elegantly given the circular convolution I need to do to get the equations (in this case 2d numpy array) in the first place.  How do I get the 2d numpy array from `coeffs`?